# Installing Ubuntu from ISO

Tags: 13.04, system-installation, iso

I'm using ubuntu for the 1st time. I was trying to install it using the ISO that i downloaded from ubuntu website.

When i run Wubi.exe i'm getting below error

```
"Not able to download metalink"..
```

Please suggest me the process

ISO:

[image]

Comment: do you considered the extraction of the iso first ?

Comment: Yes i did, it gives same error, If i have internet connection it will start downloading the iso from ubuntu again

Comment: Wubi is no longer supported. Also, why 13.04? That is also not supported — use a newer version like 16.04 or 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the problem like yours.
So, I used VMWare to install ubuntu on my hard disk.

Is it helpful to you?
If it is, I will let you know how to use VMWare to install ubuntu.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

## Install Ubuntu Using Wubi:

Step #1 = Extract wubi.exe from Ubuntu.iso. [If you don't have a a program to do this you can download 7-zip for free. Just right click and choose open with 7-zip, then drag and drop wubi.exe to the location you want.]

Step #2 = Place the Ubuntu.iso file in the directory that wubi.exe is in.

Step #3 = Double click on wubi.exe.

## Notes:

Note #1 = Wubi can only use an iso file if it's located in the same directory otherwise it can't find it.

Note #2 = Only use the same version of Ubuntu that you obtained Wubi from.

Note #3 = Wubi cannot be used with Windows 8 systems that are installed on a GPT drive.

Note #4 = The Ubuntu.iso file can be renamed and Wubi.exe will still detect it.

## Additional Resources:

Download Link For 7-zip X86-32 (XP-8.1) = http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sevenzip/7z920.exe

Download Link For 7-zip X86-64 (XP-8.1) = http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sevenzip/7z920-x64.msi